# Safari bookmarks sidebar

Tags: macos, safari, bookmarks

Is it possible anyhow to have a bookmarks sidebar (like the one in Firefox) in Safari in OSX Lion? The way bookmarks work now in Safari is very clumsy when you have thousands of bookmarks.

If not sidebar, any other system that would do the trick much better than the current one

Comment: You're among many people who want this. So far my research has been quite extensive and not yet delivered any promising results. There is no Safari extension or SIMBL plugin that even claims to do this.

Comment: ok, then I am considering to go back to firefox, that's life ...

Comment: Does Firefox in OS X even have that? Chrome doesn't either, and it's one of the most famous feature requests for Chromium, I guess.

Comment: yes, firefox in osx does the trick very neatly

Comment: but also overhauls memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Saft](http://haoli.dnsalias.com/Saft/) free plugin can supposedly do that (last download is up to Snow Leopard only).

From the article [safari sidebar](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/safari-sidebar---beta-screenshots-updated) :

> The plug-in
>   goes into the Library>InputMangers folder replacing the previous
>   version. Once launched, Safari then has the ‘Show Sidebar’ command in
>   the Safari menu (this is a temporary position).

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[EDIT]

According to your remark that Saft doesn't work on 10.7, here is an extract from the article
[Make SAFT work with newer versions of Safari Web Browsers](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060803170950202) :

> First, quit out Safari and then open the top-level Library ->
>   InputManagers -> Saft folder. Control-click on Saft.bundle and choose
>   Show Package Contents from the pop-up menu. Within the Contents
>   folder, open info.plist, either in Property List Editor or your
>   favorite text editor. There is an option for SaftSupportedSafariBuild
>   within which you can re-enter the version number from Safari's About
>   Box. Change that, save, and relaunch Safari to enjoy Saft goodness.
>
> [robg adds: Depending on how much Safari has changed, you may find
>   that Saft still won't work, or won't work properly. The Saft author is
>   usually quite good about keeping up with Safari updates, so this hint
>   should only be needed if that ever changes.]

Comment: Saft doesn't seem to work at all on 10.7.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: That quoted hint (from 2006) doesn't apply for "Saft for 10.6". (Which doesn't even install anything at `/Library/InputManagers/`.) I did look inside `/Applications/Saft.app/Contents/Info.plist` but didn't find any corresponding key for a minimum supported version.

Comment: It seems then that Saft is dead. One suggestion is maybe to get in touch with the developers of [Glims](http://www.machangout.com/) and convince them of the idea.

Comment: Safari plugins (including Glims) are pretty dead in general.